# Navigation Architecture Component - New Resource dialog doesn't have Navigation resource type for navigation graph

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-components, googleio, android-architecture-navigation

New Resource dialog doesn't have Navigation resource type for navigation graph even after adding Navigation Architecture Component dependencies

```
def nav_version = '1.0.0-alpha01'
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```

[image]

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Make sure that you checked the box **Settings -> Experimental -> Enable Navigation Editor**.

> The Navigation Editor is an experimental feature, so you must first
>   enable it by opening the IDE Settings/Preferences dialog, selecting
>   Experimental in the left pane, and checking the box next to Enable
>   Navigation Editor.
>
> **Help -> What's New in Android** (Android Studio 3.2 Beta 1)

after that , restart Android Studio

Comment: After updating "Android Studio 3.2 Beta 1",  the Design tab is not showing. Your answer saved my time. Answer is available here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50981021/2024527

Comment: I also had to restart Android Studio

Answer (score 7):

It works in Android Studio 3.2 which is in Canary at the time of writing.

> Android Studio 3.2 features tools for Android Jetpack including a
>   visual Navigation Editor and new code refactoring tools.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/google-io-2018-whats-new-in-android.html

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why it's not showing up for me either but there is a workaround.

Right click on `res` --> select `Android Resource Directory` --> select `Resource type` as `navigation` click ok --> select the newly created `navigation` directory --> right click `File` and put in the name `nav_graph.xml` --> once the file opens paste this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</navigation>
```

Comment: Navigation tag is not recognisable.

Comment: @YousufSohail did you create the file in the navigation folder?

Comment: It appears that Android Studio 3.2 beta 1 has this problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Android Studio 3.2.1 but it would not load the navigation editor. Complained about not being able to install the navigation fragment dependency. Only after I invalidated Android Studio's cache and restarted did it work.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue when I create new resource file as **Navigation Type** .

**The navigation editor tool is only available in Android Studio 3.2 Canary.**

I tried to enable Navigation editor manually:
**File → Settings → Experimental → Enable Navigation Editor**

Still the Navigation option does not appear in the selection menu.

It will appear after I restarted android studio.