# (Android Studio 3.2 Beta) - Navigation Architecture Component Configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I want to try out the new Navigation Architecture Component feature, so I followed this Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GOpeBbfyb6s.

I am using Android Studio 3.2 Beta 1. I installed the necessary dependencies, but when I try to create the **Navigation Android Resource File** in the project just like in the video above, the **Navigation** option does not appear in the selection menu.

**My Issue:**

There is no **Navigation** option to select while trying to create the **Navigation Android Resource File**. Am I missing any steps in the installation?

**Expected Result:**

[image]

**My Situation:**

[image: No Navigation Option to Select]

**My build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    // Navigation Architecture Component Configuration install HERE!!
    def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha02"

    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin


}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Per [this currently open issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110564366):

> As per the Help > What's New in Android Studio screen that popped up when you upgraded:
>
> "The Navigation Editor is an experimental feature, so you must first enable it by opening the IDE 'Settings/Preferences' dialog, selecting 'Experiemental' in the left pane, and checking the box next to the 'Enable Navigation Editor'."
>
> We'll update the Navigation documentation to specifically call this out. It will also be enabled by default on future canary builds (of Android Studio 3.3) when available.

So you need to manually enable the Navigation Editor on Beta builds of Android Studio 3.2

Comment: Note: I had to restart my Android Studio (3.2 Beta 4) in order to see "Navigation" as a Resource type after enabling the "Navigation Editor" experimental option.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue when I create new resource file as **Navigation Type** .

**The navigation editor tool is only available in Android Studio 3.2 Canary.**

I tried to enable Navigation editor manually:
File → Settings → Experimental → Enable Navigation Editor

Still the Navigation option does not appear in the selection menu.

It will appear after I restarted android studio.

Note:I followed this link 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing